# What Is The Equivalent Method For Mysql "on Duplicate Key Update" In Yii's Ar Model

Tags: php, mysql, yii

i'm trying to insert data in a table using Yii's AR model. I was wondering what is the equivalent method for MySQL's ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE command in Yii's AR.
Here is the method sample which inserts data from a huge xml feed.

```
public function insertData($name, $category, $brand, $price_unit, $weight_unit, $providers, $review_text, $flavor, $imageurl) {

    $this->productModel = new Products;
    $this->brandModel = new Brand;

    $this->brandModel->name = $brand;


    $this->brandModel->save();

    $this->productModel->name = $name;
    $this->productModel->category = $category;
    $this->productModel->brand = $brand;
    $this->productModel->weight_unit = $weight_unit;
    $this->productModel->price_unit = $price_unit;
    $this->productModel->flavors = $flavor;
    $this->productModel->providers = $providers;
    $this->productModel->review_text = $review_text;
    $this->productModel->image_path = $imageurl;


    $this->productModel->save();

}
```

As you can see i'm doing a simple insertion using save(). But i would like to implement the ON DUPLICATE KEY command of mysql.

Here is the table in question:

```
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(100)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| category    | varchar(50)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| brand       | varchar(50)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| weight      | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| weight_unit | varchar(30)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| price       | decimal(15,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| price_unit  | varchar(30)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| flavors     | varchar(45)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| providers   | varchar(45)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| review_text | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| image_path  | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

So, id is the primary key here, name has a index set on it for faster lookups. Category and brand are foreign keys.

The query which i want to replicate using Yii's ar would be something like this ::

```
INSERT INTO tbl_products (name, category, brand, weight_unit, price_unit, flavors, providers, review_text, image_path) values ('.$this->parseXML[0] .', '. 
$this->parseXML[1] .',' 
.$this->parseXML[2] .','
. $this->parseXML[3] .','
. $this->parseXML[4] .','
. $this->parseXML[5] .','
.$this->parseXML[6] .','
.$this->parseXML[7] .','
.$this->parseXML[8].') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
name = '.$this->parseXML[1].',
category = '.$this->parseXML[2].',
brand = '.$this->parseXML[3].'
```

So, what i the efficient method to do this using Yii's AR. I'm trying to avoid using brute force methods, as much as i can.

Thanks, in advance.I would really appreciate any help that i can get on this.

thanks,
Maxx

Comment: on duplicate key update, only works on primary key or unique indexes. Which column is unique index in your table?

Comment: the id column is the primary key and i've indexed the name column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a unique validation rule in your model. Then catch when this rule is violated and use a conditional block to process the data in case duplicate value is encountered...

In model rules

```
array('id', 'unique','message'=>'duplicate value entered'),
```

In controller:

```
$this->brandModel->validate(); 
.......
.......

if ($this->brandModel->getError('id')==='duplicate value entered')
{
....
....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already have unique key set for name and id is the primary key, in the table. So if this rule gets violated when the validate is called will it throw an exception or do i have to use the getError() method

Comment: Just when would i call the validate method. Before saving or afte saving the model

Comment: Exception will occur in case any of the validation rule is failed. If you want to check for a specific rule failing you need to use getError(). Call validate first and if validated then call model save.